# Uncaught TypeError thrown for using Global Constants across JS files in MVC app

Tags: extjs, global-variables, constants, extjs4.2

I have a Constants.js file that defines a set of constants.

```
Ext.define('My.app.util.Constants', {
    singleton: true,
    var1: 'ABC',
    var2: '979082'
});
```

I want to use these variables across different js files within my app.

**Update:**

I have a Common.js file and I try using var1 as

```
var myVariable1 = My.app.util.Constants.var1;
```

This throws an error  **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'var1' of undefined**.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you ever require `My.app.util.Constants`?

Comment: Ext.require() is what you mean ? I tried that as well. The error seems to be thrown intermittently.

Comment: Yes, in your app.js, add it as part of your `requires` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **statics**!

```
Ext.define('My.app.util.Constants', {
    statics: {
        var1: 'ABC',
        var2: '979082'
    }
});
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work with singleton: true. Otherwise , it's fine. Thanks much